# Out of date HTML and CSS when debugging

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, debugging

I'm just doing some web, but sometimes, when I want to debug, the whole web is out of date. I've already read some threads here, but the problem is I set it to "When out of date, prompt to launch". It doesn't say anything, it just start the browser and do its job.
Could you please help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Your questions is not clear. Could you please explain it more and share your code?

Comment: @Messon，what about this issue? Would you please let me know that latest information in your side?

Comment: Everything's good now, thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the build option
“**Prompt to build”：Displays the message box every time that a project configuration is out of date.**

Like this document here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyhcc7zc.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

It is used for the VC++ project only.

[image]

[image]